# Copied JSON data shows as string in node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodes

I wrote a code where I am copying a one json file into another json file so my code look like this

```
function userData(){

     fs.copyFile(
      path.join(process.cwd(), "user/access.json"),
      path.join(process.cwd(), "client/access.json"),
      (err) => {
        if (err) throw console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
}
```

so my json structure look like this

```
{
 "Data":{
   "users":[
    {},
    {},
    {},
   ]
 }
}
```

So I am reading json the copied json file like this

```
fs.readFile(path.join(process.cwd(), "client/access.json"), 'utf8', function(err, data){
      
    console.log(typeof data); // showing as a string as it should shown me as object

    // console.log(data.Data.users); // showing undefined
});
```

but the problem is the `typeof` of data showing me `string` as it should be shown as Object so I can read the data.Data.users but now I can't read this any solution whats happening here?

Comment: You have to call `JSON.parse()` to convert the JSON string to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you read file file is always a string. To convert it to an JSON object you need to do JSON.parse

```
fs.readFile(path.join(process.cwd(), "client/access.json"), 'utf8', function(err, data){
      
    console.log(typeof data); // showing as a string as it should shown me as object
    const obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log( typeof obj);

    // console.log(data.Data.users); // showing undefined
});
```

Comment: Its giving me error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`